# how to select multiple music files from device,and to save those selected files in some whare

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am able to select images from phone..using universal load jar file..but now i need to select music files using intent chooser i am going to gallery,there i can able to select music files but after selecting music files i need to save those music files in some other place in phone but how to save those selected music files i didn't get,any one suggest me thanks..

```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity {
         Button email;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    email=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    email.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("audio/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), 2);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like there is a way to select multiple files below API 19. See [Select multiple files with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513556/select-multiple-files-with-intent-action-get-content)