# how to get multiple selected files path for my activity-android

Tags: android, batch-processing, image-gallery, android-implicit-intent

So far I know how to get a file path by calling fileChooser which always returns one particular file path, but now I want a batch selection returning with multiple file paths(5 file in my case). Is there any way to that?

Plus, is there any way that from Gallery I can share multiple pic with my app??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

API Level 18 sneaked in a new standard for ACTION_GET_CONTENT that addresses a long-standing request: multiple selections. Check following links for details.

http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/10/22/action_get_content-support-extra_allow_multiple-please.html

[Select multiple files with Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513556/select-multiple-files-with-intent-action-get-content)

Comment: So, what about those lower level API. I mean, I even myself don't have a device running kitkat. I would like to make it accessible at least on ICS and Jellybean.

Comment: No way at least at this moment. :(

Comment: Now what I am doing for multiple selection I'm letting user select one pic by one time, then again one and it goes on(i have 5 separated field to select those) but now I want user to select multiple file at a time. Or directly share those picture from the gallery. Can you help me with that??

Comment: You see, there are thousands application out there,which allowing user to select multiple picture at a time.So, there definitely should be a way to accomplish this. Even on gingerbread.

Comment: really thanks for your great efforts. But this is not exactly what I wanted. However, Thanks again. :)