# multiple image choose in android xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

in my app in one activity user can select multiple image from the gallery.
the code is

```
 Intent i = new Intent();
                i.SetType("image/*");
                i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraLocalOnly, true);
                i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
                i.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
                act.StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(i, "Select Picture"), 202);
```

see i write this code

```
   i.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraAllowMultiple, true);
```

and it is work good in the emulator but in the phone when the gallery is open and user long click on the image , no imgage selected
how can i resolve this.

Comment: The app providing the gallery has to support this function.  Have you tried more than one gallery provider?  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513556/select-multiple-files-with-intent-action-get-content

Comment: i dont understand

Comment: @amirjahany As Dylan stated, not all Gallery apps support multiple image selections via `ExtraAllowMultiple`, it depends upon what Gallery apps are installed on the device and which one that user chooses...

Comment: @SushiHangover what can i do?

Comment: @amirjahany Write your own file browser that supports multiple file selection.

Comment: @SushiHangover do you have example for it?

Comment: @Dylan what can i do????

Comment: There are a ton of useful thoughts in this thread:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23426113/how-to-select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-android