# how to fetch data to show preview from dynamic link

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I tried libraries such as `rich link preview`, `urlembeddedview`, `android preview link`.

But it is failing to load the preview for my link: https://mydomainname.page.link/ay1q4rpCSR45NisV6

But when I type on whatsapp the whatsapp is generating the preview don't know how they are generating.

Code which I tried using `urlembeddedview` library:

```java
if (linearLayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE&&!linkPosted.isEmpty()) {

    urlEmbeddedView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    urlEmbeddedView.setURL(linkPosted, new URLEmbeddedView.OnLoadURLListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadURLCompleted(URLEmbeddedData data) {
            urlEmbeddedView.title(data.getTitle());
            urlEmbeddedView.description(data.getDescription());
            urlEmbeddedView.host(data.getHost());
            urlEmbeddedView.thumbnail(data.getThumbnailURL());
            urlEmbeddedView.favor(data.getFavorURL());
        }
    });

}
else {
    urlEmbeddedView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Output is giving host URL name but not title, description, image, but somehow whatsapp does display this.

Need help. Thanks in advance.